# docker bind socket to outside port

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, docker

I'm using docker. Inside docker I have app that binds listening socket to ip of outside machine (ip of machine where I have docker running). is there any way I can make such listening socket work? that's bound to outside ip address (192.168.1.2) and not docker's eth0 (172.17.0.248)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay fixed myself:
add new ip via "ip addr add", then make iptable rule to preroute incoming packets to that ip and thats all :)

Answer (score 2):

When you run the container map the port to the external port you want to reach it on.  `docker run -p 80:80 myapp`  This will let you access the docker container at 192.168.1.2:80.  The command format is -p {external port}:{internal app port}.

For further clarification.  To access any application inside a container you will want to expose the port, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/usingdocker/).  Essentially you map a port from the container to the host o/s.

Example: You have an application running on port 8080 in your container, but you want to access it with your host ip at port 8000.  You would run your app like so `docker run -p 8000:8080 myapp`.  This will expose port 8080 to your host o/s as port 8000 at which point you could reach it at {host ip}:8000.

Comment: yes but I have to bind socket inside docker to 172.17.0.2:80 then, not 192.168.1.2:80

Comment: @JaniBaramidze No, you should bind it to `0.0.0.0:80` actually, and let port forwarding do its magic. You can't bind to an IP address that isn't local to your local host.

Comment: cannot we do something "hacky" about it to make it work? because I cannot change source code of the program that binds it to outside ip

Comment: can you clarify exactly what you are trying to do and how you have it setup?  if you want to expose a container port to the host o/s. you only need to use the -p command to reach it with the host ip.

Comment: @JaniBaramidze You cannot do the impossible. But it's also impossible to believe that the source code has `172.17.0.2:80` hardwired into it. Suppose you state your *real* problem?

Comment: I'm trying to implement mariadb cluster inside docker, IST starts listening to node ip, which is ip that it's accessible by (outside machine's ip). it has option to change it, changed it to 0.0.0.0 but then other peer starts connecting to 0.0.0.0. that's the real problem